# How to display only US in country dropdown in Shipping Address in Checkout page?

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-address, checkout-page

I wanted to display only US in country dropdown list in checkout page in shipping address form.

Comment: If solution is useful then accept as answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple you can manage countries under store configuration settings.

**Follow below steps :**

> Go to -> Store -> Configuration -> General -> Allow countries ->
>   Select "United States"

Comment: This setting applicable for the billing address also, is there have any way only for the shipping address country drop-down